# How three drop down lists depend on each other and using these three drop down list grid view data display?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three drop down lists which depend on each other and using these three drop down lists grid view filtered data is displayed. (single drop down filter is also not  working there) It gives output but it executes else part first and then displays output (means it gives a message first like `'No data found'` after that result displays)

The code is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="form-control1 text" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" style= "margin-left: -30px; width: 174px; margin-top: -4px;" > </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Can you give some code for better understanding?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" class="form-control1 text" AutoPostBack="true" onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" style= "margin-left: -30px; width: 174px;  margin-top: -4px;" >
                                 
                                   </asp:DropDownList>

Comment: if (branchId == "All")
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from vehicle where m_city='" + Label4.Text + "' AND Vehical_status='Unapprove'", con);
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

            else{
                Response.Write("<script>alert('Result Not Found)</script>");
            }
        }

Comment: else {
      MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from vehicle where merch_name='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "' AND m_city='" + Label4.Text + "' AND Vehical_status='Unapprove' ", con)     MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }

        }
    }

Comment: I sending aspx code and cs code of only  one drop down because it takes limited code.how to send all three drop down list code ?